# Generate Bulk Unique Strings in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, function, substr

I have a ***working*** script designed to generate and output a bulk number of unique strings after checking a database and/or text document (this is not included yet - but I'm not requesting assistance with regards to checking against the database) and to check the already generated strings in the same request.

I did try this with a single function, but I didn't know how to get so many checks in one function, thus this code just feels very long for what I am trying to achieve.

I was hoping the community would be able to assist me with the most appropriate and/or compliant way to undertake the following task with either the least amount of requests or if the code can be secured and simplified in some way?

The script basically takes a 'range' or a limit input and generates that number of random strings (eg: aa0aa0) into a table. I'm using `substr()`, `str_shuffle()` and `str_repeat()`, but I have seen other uses such as `mt_rand()` but have not attempted to change this code in fear of breaking it.

I posted this because there are no easy ways to do '***reverse regex***' except for some quite complex functions, but I found this to be an easy way if the string format was already stipulated in the code.

Any thoughts and/or assistance would be appreciated.

```
<?php

/**
 * This just stops the errors that a unset/zero range throws 
 * back with populateRandomString() and exportRandomString().
 */
if( isset( $_REQUEST['range'] ) ) {
    
    $range = $_REQUEST['range'];
    
    if( $range == 0 ) {
        
        unset( $range );
    }
    
}
if( !isset( $_REQUEST['range'] ) ) {
    
    $range = null;
    
} ?>

<h3>Generate Strings</h3>

<form><input type="text" name="range" value="<?php if( isset( $range ) ) { echo $range; } else { echo ''; } ?>"><input type="submit" action="" ></form>

<?php
function generateRandomString() {
    
    /**
     * This is just a hack for when existing values from this 
     * function are saved, either in a text document or database.
     */
    $db_existing = ''; // Will eventually call the database or text file.
    $existing_array = explode( ',', $db_existing );
    
    /**
     * Combinations of letters and numbers that will be generated by 
     * generateRandomString().
     */
    $letter = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $number = '0123456789';

    start:
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++) {

        /**
         * I could not find any research that supported regex developing certain
         * strings (simply), so this is the only way that I could do it. I'm
         * looking for the most efficient way to generate these strings
         */
        $generateString  = substr ( str_shuffle ( str_repeat ( $letter, 2 ) ), 1 , 2 );
        $generateString .= substr ( str_shuffle ( str_repeat ( $number, 1 ) ), 1 , 1 );
        $generateString .= substr ( str_shuffle ( str_repeat ( $letter, 2 ) ), 1 , 2 );
        $generateString .= substr ( str_shuffle ( str_repeat ( $number, 1 ) ), 1 , 1 );
        // output example: aa0aa0
    }
    
    /**
     * If the random generated string has already been generated and is part
     * of the existing strings (database or text file, it will ignore it and
     * cycle again.
     */
    if ( in_array ( $generateString, $existing_array ) ) {
        
        goto start;
        
    } else {
        
        return $generateString;
        
    }

}
if( isset( $range ) ) {
    
    function populateRandomString() {
        
        global $range;
        
        /**
         * If the string has already been generated in this request, ignore it
         * and generate it again until the range (limit) has been met.
         */
        
        start :
        for( $i = 0; $i < $range; $i++ ) {
            
            $populateRandomString[] = generateRandomString();
            
        }
        
        if( count( array_unique( $populateRandomString ) ) < $range ) {
                
            unset( $populateRandomString);
            goto start;
        
        } else {

            return $populateRandomString;
        
        }

    }

    function exportRandomString() {

        global $range;
        
        /**
         * Display the generated strings in a table as described in the html
         * output below.
         */
        
        for ( $e = 0; $e < $range; $e++ ) {

            $id[] = populateRandomString();

        }
        
    }
    $id = populateRandomString(); ?>
    
<table id="myTable" width="50%">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th scope="col">Title 1</th>
    <th scope="col">Title 2</th>
    <th scope="col">ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    
    <?php foreach ( $id as $i ) { ?>
  <tr>  
    <td>https://www.example.com/<?php echo $i; ?></td>
    <td>https://www.example.com/<?php echo $i; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo strtoupper($i); ?></td>
  </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
<style>
  #myTable{
     font-family: 'helvetica neue',helvetica,arial,'lucida grande',sans-serif;
     border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  #myTable td{
     border: solid 1px #C9C9C9;
     padding: 10px;
     font-size: 12px;
     text-align: left;
  }
  #myTable th {
      text-align: left;
  }
  #myTable tr{
     background-color: #EBEBEB;
     color: #000000;
  }
  #myTable tr:hover{
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     color: #000000;
  }

</style>    
    <?php
}
```

Comment: I would say that even by your solution, the chance of getting a repeated string is essentially zero for a real world scenario. In any case, you could simplify a lot by simply using, for example, [random_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) for generating your (pseudo) random string.

Comment: Perplexed? That paragraph was only to state I havent been able to find a command that allows you to eg: `generate_string('regex('{[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2}2}')`. (Just an example)... The random string is still formatted within the code.

Comment: @nitrin0 thanks for your comments. I'll have a look at `random_bytes()`

Comment: Cheers @Aliqua. Here's [one additional implementation](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9ffaa400770341c85b93a824d3d0823091b321f7) for you (not fully tested, use for learning purposes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really specify your question a lot more and clean up your code. It is very messy to look at and even more messy to work with. Nevertheless, I gave it an attempt.

I used docker-compose with one container running apache, and the other MySQL. I added prepared statement support, which seems sort of overkill for this application, but is good practise anyways. You will however need to update the database information in the PHP-code.

This is my attempt:

```php
<?php

    // Simplified below code. 
    $range = null;
    if( isset( $_REQUEST['range'] ) && $_REQUEST['range'] != 0 ) {
            $range = intval($_REQUEST['range']);
    }

    
    //                          db host        user    pass    db schema
    if ($conn = mysqli_connect("overflow_db", "root", "test", "testone")) {} else { // Here you will have to update the credentials for your database.
        die("could not connect to database. :(");
    }
    


    function getAllStringsDb() {
        // Grab all previously generated strings from db and load into $existing_array (array) on global scope.

        global $existing_array; // Declare the existing strings on a global scope.
        $existing_array = array();

        $conn = $GLOBALS['conn'];
        
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM stored_strings";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if ($result->num_rows === 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $existing_array[] = $row['string_value'];
            }
        }
        $stmt->close();

        return $existing_array;

    }

    function saveNewStringsToDb($return_array) {

        $conn = $GLOBALS['conn'];
        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO stored_strings (string_value) VALUES (?)";
        
        foreach ($return_array as $value) {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $value);

            if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                die("DB save failed. :( ");
            }

            $stmt->close();
        }

    }


    function getString($existing_array) {
        $string_length = 6;

        $characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        start:
        $generateString = '';
        for ($n = 0; $n < $string_length; $n++) {

            $generateString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
        }

        if ( in_array ( $generateString, $existing_array ) ) {
            goto start;
        } else {
            // Add new string to db.
            $existing_array[] = $generateString;
            return $generateString;
        }
    }

    function generateRandomStrings($range) {

        // Generate all the new strings into the array $return_array.
        for ($i = 0; $i < $range; $i++) {
            $return_array[] = getString([]);
        }

        // Upload all the newly generated strings to the database. 
        saveNewStringsToDb($return_array);

        return $return_array; // Return array.

    }

?>



<h3>Generate Strings</h3>

<form>
    <input type="number" name="range" value="<?php if (isset($range)) { echo $range; } else { echo ''; } ?>" />
    <input type="submit" action="" />
</form>




<?php
    if( isset( $range ) ) {

        getAllStringsDb(); // Load in all previously generated strings into the array $existing_array from the database.
        
        $ids = generateRandomStrings($range);
?>

<table id="myTable" width="50%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Title 1</th>
            <th scope="col">Title 2</th>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <?php foreach ( $ids as $i ) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td>https://www.example.com/<?php echo $i; ?></td>
                <td>https://www.example.com/<?php echo $i; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo strtoupper($i); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>

<style>
    #myTable {
        font-family: 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, 'lucida grande', sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    #myTable td {
        border: solid 1px #C9C9C9;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    #myTable th {
        text-align: left;
    }

    #myTable tr {
        background-color: #EBEBEB;
        color: #000000;
    }

    #myTable tr:hover {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        color: #000000;
    }
</style>
<?php
    }
?>
```

And here is the basic database structure I used for the above code:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stored_strings`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `stored_strings` (
  `string_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `string_value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`string_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=416 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

I would urge you though to rewrite your code from scratch, to try to make it nicer. Also, take the code I provided above with a grain of salt, as it is a simple draft based on your existing code. :)

Comment: Firstly thank you for your contribution. I will definitely try your version. Secondly my code is just a single page localhost table generator I coded (no need for separate css files etc). Its format is clean, well spaced, noted, I dont know how I could make it any easier to read (except for the reasons explained in my question). I specified that I wrote working code and simply wanted feedback to make it more efficient. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem. Hope the code works! Please get back to us with the results. :)
With regards to my critique of your code I was referring to `$populateRandomString` having the same name as a function, the spacing and indentations in your code being inconsistent, not properly closing the HTML-tags (e.g. `<input >` should be `<input />`), etc. Not critical errors and my code is not ideal either don't get me wrong. But you should polish it before production and further updates.